# Heroku Relocating dyno to a new server

Tags: heroku, server, dyno

Is there a way to prevent Heroku "Relocating dyno to a new server"?

Since Relocating does not make a copy of the code, my scheduler stops from working.
It's annoying !

Thanks

Comment: Have your scheduler outside of the app deployed on heroku. Use this: https://elements.heroku.com/addons/scheduler

Comment: I have the addon scheduler that runs at midnight. This scheduler programs the sending of notifications during the day. When Heroku relocates my scheduler, no more notifications is sent.

Comment: I see, keep your notifications in a different service, not heroku, you can't prevent "Relocating dyno to a new server".

Comment: ok thank your for your help,  which service do you recommend ?